# agregar div a un div especifico clonado

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

estoy tratando de insertar un div a un div clonado peor por ejemplo específicamente a ese, es decir lo que quiero es que cuando le piques a un recuadro y se expanda aparezca no se un área donde yo pueda poner divs y después si quiero a otro recuadro pues algo diferente, me imagino que debo de usar ID para lograr la tarea pero de ahí en adelante no me imagino como puede ser [Este es mi código hasta ahorita](https://jsfiddle.net/89zxbsnb/2/)

```
     $("body").delegate('.box', 'click', function() {

     if ($('.box.active').length <= 0) {

     $(this).addClass('cloned');

     var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
     var pos = $(this).position();
     var clone = $(this).clone().addClass('active');
     $(this).css({
       left: pos.left + 'px',
       top: pos.top + 'px'
     });

     parent.append(clone);

     clone.css({
       position: 'fixed',
       left: pos.left + 'px',
       top: pos.top + 'px',
       margin: '0 auto'
     }).animate({
       width: '100%',
       height: '100%',
       margin: '0 auto',
       'z-index': '10',
       top: 0,
       left: 0
     }, 300);

   }


 });

 $("body").delegate('.box.active', 'click', function() {

   var cloned = $('.box.cloned');
   var clone = $('this');
   var pos = cloned.position();
   var w = cloned.width();
   var h = cloned.height();

   $(this).animate({
     width: w + 'px',
     height: h + 'px',
     top: pos.top + 'px',
     left: pos.left + 'px'

   }, 300, function() {
     $('.box.active').remove();
     cloned.removeClass('cloned');
     $(".greetings").removeClass('test');
   });

 });

 $(window).ready(function() {

   $(".bgCity ").click(function() {
     $(".greetings").addClass('test');
   });

   $(".bgCity.active ").click(function() {
     $(".greetings").removeClass('test');
   });


   $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
   });
   $('button.btnbig').on('click', function(e) {
     $(this).toggleClass('show');
   });

   var colors = ['orange', 'saddlebrown', 'royalblue', 'crimson', 'darkcyan', 'mediumvioletred', 'yellowgreen', 'indigo', 'green', 'olivedrab', 'thistle', 'darkolivegreen', 'chocolate', 'palevioletred', 'darkred', 'goldenrod', 'deepskyblue', 'slatblue', 'dodgerblue'];
   var boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
   for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
     // Pick a random color from the array 'colors'.
     boxes[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
   }


   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.addJourn').click(function() {
       var currentCount = $('.repeatingSection').length;
       var newCount = currentCount + 1;
       var lastRepeatingGroup = $('.repeatingSection').last();
       var newSection = lastRepeatingGroup.clone();
       newSection.insertAfter(lastRepeatingGroup);
       newSection.find("select").each(function(index, select) {
         select.id = select.id.replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount);
         select.name = select.name.replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount);
         select.onchange = function(event) {
           onChange(event)
         };
       });
       newSection.find("label").each(function(index, label) {
         var l = $(label);
         l.attr('for', l.attr('for').replace("_" + currentCount, "_" + newCount));
       });
       newSection.find('.hidden').css('display', 'none');
       return false;
     });

     $('#j_id_1').change(function(event) {
       onChange(event);
     });
   });



 });
```

Con este codigo genero mis cajas clones 
Cualquier sugerencia o ayuda se los agradeceria bastante

Comment: Siempre que sea posible, debe incluirse el código en la pregunta misma. Véase [mcve].

Comment: @Godeolo te refieres a un tipo modal por cada recuadro?

Comment: No me queda muy claro, según entiendo, en la pantalla principal tienes una especie de marcos, cuando picas a cada uno este se clona y se expande ocupando toda la pantalla, entonces deseas que este clon tenga una especie de área para editar sus elementos o añadirle contenido. Si es así, puedes poner esta área en los marcos principales con el atributo oculto y al expandir quitarles ese atributo.